# show a not available page to user on MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

For my project, i plan on displaying a Page not available page when user types in wrong controller name and action links in the browser.

```
for example: www.myproject.com/home/away
```

doesn't exist. How can i display such cases when there is no controller of that name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd usually get a **[404 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)** in this case, so you could use custom errors in your config file.

Under `<system.web>`, add..

```
 <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/myCustom404"/>
    </customErrors>
```